# calling fdopen: Bad file descriptor

Tags: c, gcc, fdopen

I'm getting the following error when trying to compile my program:

`calling fdopen: Bad file descriptor`

I've read this might be a problem related to including a precompiled header in one of my header files.  The file which is causing the error includes the stdio.h header in it so I have access to the FILE type. If I remove this, the error disappears, but then I can't use the FILE type.  Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Comment: Try isolating the problem into a bare bones program (--i.e., a new seperate file with a main in it and only the code that fails). Then update your question. We can't give feedback without some code.

Comment: Can you post the simplest self-contained code that reproduces the issue you are experiencing?

Comment: Source code please? We're not psychic debuggers nor clairvoyants...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I just forgot to include the stdio.h header file.  I feel kind of stupid now.

Answer (score 6):

Hard to tell without details, but it's indeed most probably due to an out-of-date precompiled header. Remove all `.gch` files and try again.

This is frequently reported as a bug against GCC, see the bugzilla entry [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/PR15118)